# Can AMP be added to Visualforce page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I would like to know if there is a way to add Accelerated Mobile Pages in Visualforce. I tried to add but salesforce is throwing error. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: Its like the tags are not supported in visual force.

Answer (score 0):

VF Pages have built-in JavaScript that you cannot prevent from loading.  This will break the requirements of AMP pages.